# Decrease padding in \boxed

Tags: math-mode, framed

I am using `\boxed` to draw a small box around a symbol in math mode. I would, however, like to decrease the padding between the symbol and the box. While I found solutions involving other commands/packages, I'd prefer to stuck to stick to `\boxed`. Also, adding `\smash` does not work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[ \boxed{\leq} \quad \boxed{\smash{\leq}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\boxed` in [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is defined using a regular `\fbox`:

```
\newcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}
```

So, setting `\fboxsep` would modify the gap. Here is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\[
  \boxed{\leq} \quad 
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{.5\fboxsep}\boxed{\leq} \quad
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{.5\fboxsep}\boxed{\leq} \quad
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{.5\fboxsep}\boxed{\leq}
\]

\end{document}
```

In that sense it's possible to redefine `\boxed` to take an optional argument that sets the width:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\boxed}[2][\fboxsep]{{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{#1}\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#2$}}}
\makeatother
```

This allows one to use, for example, `\boxed[-\fboxrule]{\leq}` to see the bounding box around `\leq`.

Comment: But your first example above seems to make the change to `\boxed` somewhat permanent, i.e. if I later use another plain `\boxed` without changes to `\fboxsep`, the padding is still decreased. How would I make the one-shot padding-decreased smaller box without affecting future ones? - Other than that, the solution works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Bernd: I've added an example of how to update `\boxed` to take an optional argument which does a local change to `\fboxsep`. However, if you wish to do this manually, surround the `\setlength...\boxed..` with braces: `{\setlength...\boxed..}`. That defines the scope for the change.

Comment: Ah, the braces did the trick. Still know so little about how the LaTeX syntax works. Thanks!